# jQuery display as its in mobile device in Magento

Tags: android, jquery, magento, mobile

I wrote the code for mini cart. This is working fine in desktop but in mobile device its not working and code is showing as its in mobile browser. I am using below code.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#mini-cart').mouseover(function(){ 
        jQuery( this ).addClass('open');
        jQuery( this ).children('.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        jQuery( this ).removeClass('open');
        jQuery( this ).children('.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
    });
});
</script>
```

Please someone help me on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. This is designing issue. Designer put `*` and `display: block` in css that was applying on all elements. like.

```
.myclass > * {
   display: block;
 }
```

This is the issue that's why jquery is showing in browser.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote `mouseover()` and `mouseout()` function. So it will work only in desktop. How do you access mouse in mobile ..?

Comment: Ok, but why code is showing as its in browser. like jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#mini-cart').mouseover(function(){ //dropdown-menu left-hand
            jQuery( this ).addClass('open');
            jQuery( this ).children('.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
        }).mouseout(function() {
            jQuery( this ).removeClass('open');
            jQuery( this ).children('.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

try by changing open script tag to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```